# editing an array field in Firebase flutter dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

im trying to update an array field in a collection i have in Firebase
this array is for course code and course section it is in this format:
"csc123:12345"
the first part of the string is before the : is the course code the latter is the course section .

i don't know how to search and update the course code alone without changing the course section and vice versa

this is a screen shot of my Firebase

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your sections like this:

```
Sections: [
 {
   "course": "csc123",
   "section": "3214"
 },
 {
   "course": "csc456",
   "section": "2346"
 }
]
```

Comment: no i do not wish to change the structure if possible . i need a way suites this structure